# Paypal Sandbox to run a function after payment is completed

Tags: php, jquery, paypal

I got a total value that the user has to pay after making all their selections. 
I used jquery to update the input value and add it dynamically into the html.

Once they click on 'pay now', a sandbox popup window opens where the user has to login into their paypal account and complete the payment.

How can I check that the payment is completed in php? Right now I have a form on my website that when all filled out, after the payment is verified, it should be submitted automatically (or show a button to complete the submission).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know the status of the payment once the transaction is complete, you would need to use either [PDT](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/) or [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/).

I would recommend IPN which is more secure.

> Instant Payment Notification (IPN) is a message service that
>   automatically notifies merchants of events related to PayPal
>   transactions. Merchants can use it to automate back-office and
>   administrative functions, like fulfilling orders and providing
>   customers with order status.

Simple Instruction for IPN:
`Pre-requieste`:

Enable **IPN** in your paypal profile.

1) Sample code:

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="XXX@gmail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="test">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="https://XXX.com/ipn.php?email_address=vravichandran@paypal.com">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_GB/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal – The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

2) Check notify_url in above URL where your IPN listener file should reside.

3) Sample IPN listener file [here](https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples) can be downloaded here.

Just run the above code and check your IPN history in your paypal profile.

Comment: is there any clear step-by-step tutorial that shows how to install IPN other than the one paypal provides? the one from paypal is a little advanced for me i feel..

Comment: When I enable the IPN, should the Notification URL be the main https://xxx.com/ or https://xxx.com/ipn.php ? Also, I downloaded the files and placed it in my root folder. So after the user clicks submit and goes through the form, once he is done paying, where can i place my function to run upon verified payment?

Comment: should be xxx.com/ipn.php 
you need put your logic/function inside ipn listener file

Comment: okay im getting the idea slowly. In the ipn.php file, there is a bunch of commented out lines " // check whether the payment_status is Completed // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
 // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
 // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
 // process payment and mark item as paid." what should i put to check if the payment went successful for $_GET['email_address']?